# Cannot open file using dbms_lob.filopen but can open it using utl_file

Tags: oracle

What could cause the following behaviour:

Database 11gR2

```
declare
   l_amt        number := dbms_lob.lobmaxsize;
   l_dst_loc    clob;
   l_dst_offset number := 1;
   l_lang_ctx   number := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
   l_src_loc    bfile;
   l_src_offset number := 1;
   l_warning    number;
begin

   l_src_loc := bfilename('ODS_SERVER_DIRECTORY', '_CIVKD_ASU.CSV');
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_dst_loc, true);
   dbms_lob.fileopen(l_src_loc, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
   dbms_lob.loadclobfromfile(l_dst_loc
                            ,l_src_loc
                            ,l_amt
                            ,l_dst_offset
                            ,l_src_offset
                            ,dbms_lob.default_csid
                            ,l_lang_ctx
                            ,l_warning);
   commit;

   dbms_lob.fileclose(l_src_loc);
   dbms_output.put_line(substr(l_dst_loc, 1, 200));

end;
/ 

ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
.
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 805
ORA-06512: in line 31
22288. 00000 -  "file or LOB operation %s failed\n%s"
*Cause:    The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed.
*Action:   See the next error message in the error stack for more detailed
           information.  Also, verify that the file or LOB exists and that
           the necessary privileges are set for the specified operation. If
           the error still persists, report the error to the DBA.
```

However opening and reading the exact same file succeeds when using utl_file.

```
declare
   l_file utl_file.file_type;
   l_regel varchar2(4000);
begin

   l_file := utl_file.fopen('ODS_SERVER_DIRECTORY', '_CIVKD_ASU.CSV', 'R');
   -- Haal de volgende regel op
   utl_file.get_line(l_file, l_regel);

   dbms_output.put_line(l_regel);
   utl_file.fclose_all;
end;
```

So it seems the file is available and accessable by the database.

It's the first time we run into this particular error and it's one of the first 11gR2 instances so maybe there is something 11g specific we don't know about?

=== Update 8-6-2012 ===
Some progress made. It turns out the directory object points to a shared drive. It's a windows server and Oracle runs as Local System. I always thought that it was impossible to read anything from a shared drive in this situation. Apparently in some situations you can using utl_file but not usign dbms_lob.

Answer (score 1):

Could you confirm that ODS_SERVER_DIRECTORY is an actual DIRECTORY

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dba_objects
WHERE
    object_type = 'DIRECTORY'
    AND object_name = 'ODS_SERVER_DIRECTORY'
```

Possibly you have it set in the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter of init.ora (should not be done anymore..)

But its one possibility as to why utl_file would see the directory and dbms_lob would not.

Comment: Just because you're not supposed to use UTL_FILE_DIR doesn't mean your DBA won't insist upon it.

Comment: Thanks, it is most certainly a DIRECTORY. Everything tells me it should work but it just doesn't. Last resort is to restart the entire server, but that wasn't possible today.